# OWL: inverse of a property

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege, pellet

Let's say we have four properties :

```
ObjectProperty: superProp1 
       InverseOf: superProp3   

ObjectProperty: prop1  
      InverseOf: prop2       
      SubPropertyOf:superProp1   

ObjectProperty: prop2  
      InverseOf: prop1   

ObjectProperty: superProp3
```

Pellet deduces that `prop2` is a subproperty of `superProp3`.
I can't understand this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `:a :prop2 :b`, one can infer that `:a :superProp3 :b` (for any `:a` and `:b`):

1. Let's suppose that `:a :prop2 :b`.
2. Then `:b :prop1 :a` holds, because `:prop2` is an inverse of `:prop1`.
3. Then `:b :superProp1 :a` holds, because `:prop1` is a subproperty of `:superProp1`.
4. Then  `:a :superProp3 :b` holds, because `:superProp1` is an inverse of `:superProp3`.

Slightly more formally:

```
T1.  :a :prop1 :b <=> :b prop2 :a              #  :prop1 owl:inverseOf :prop2  
T2.  :a :prop1 :b => :a :superProp1 :b         #  :prop1 rdfs:subPropertyOf :superProp1
T3.  :a :superProp1 :b <=> :b :superProp3 :a   #  :superProp1 owl:inverseOf :superProp3

A1.  :a :prop2 :b                              #  assumption, eliminated by T4
A2.  :b :prop1 :a                              #  A1, T1, modus ponens
A3.  :b :superProp1 :a                         #  A2, T2, modus ponens
A4.  :a :superProp3 :b                         #  A3, T3, modus ponens

T4.  :a :prop2 :b => :a :superProp3 :b         #  A1, A4, deduction theorem; QED
```

---

More info:

- [9.2.1 Object Subproperties](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-syntax/#Object_Subproperties)
- [9.2.4 Inverse Object Properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-syntax/#Inverse_Object_Properties_2)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using less abstract naming can give you a feeling of what's going on. Lets consider the same problem described using words having a semantic.

We know the following rules :
Being Wet is the inverse of being Dry.
It exist another kind of wetness, ReallyWet. Being ReallyWet always imply you're Wet, thus it is a subproperty of Wet.
Finally, we also know that being ReallyWet is the opposite of being ReallyDry.

From this you -and pellet- can then conclude that ReallyDry is a kind of dryness.

Why ? The reasoning is : 
Dry is the inverde of Wet
ReallyDry is the inverse of ReallyWet
ReallyWet is a subproperty of Wet
-> 
ReallyDry is the inverse of a subproperty of Wet, and as such is should be the subproperty of the inverse of Wet. Conclusion :  ReallyWet is a subproperty of Wet.

Does it sound logic ? I think that pellet can explain the rule it used to deduce some triples.
It probably is :
( A inverse of B ) AND 
( C inverse of D ) AND
(C is a sub property of A) -> 
 D is a sub property of B